# the range of trace on projections of II$_1$ factor

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $M$ is a von Neumann algebra factor of type II$_1$ factor,let $P(M)$ be the set of projections in $M$,how to prove that $\{tr (p),p\in P(M)\}=[0,1]$,where tr is a tracial state on $M$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly $\operatorname{tr}(P(M))\subset[0,1]$.  For the other inclusion, first note that $0,1\in\operatorname{tr}(P(M))$.  Since $M$ is a II$_1$-factor, for each projection $p\in P(M)$ there exist two equivalent projections $q,r\in P(M)$ such that $p=q+r$.  Repeating this halving process ad infinitum, we see that $\{2^{-n}:n\in\mathbb N\}\subset\operatorname{tr}(P(M))$.  From this, by adding orthogonal projections constructed above, we see that the collection of dyadic rationals in $[0,1]$, i.e., those rationals of the form $n/2^m$, where $m\in\mathbb N$ and $0\leq n\leq 2^m$, lie in $\operatorname{tr}(P(M))$.  Taking now weak limits of sums of orthogonal projections constructed above fills up $[0,1]$.

Comment: Note that this only works if the trace you're working with is the unique faithful, tracial state.  I say this because the question states "where $\operatorname{tr}$ is *a* trace on $M$".

Comment: A II$_1$ factor has a unique trace. Which happens to be faithful and normal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I knkw precious little about von Neumann algebra theory.

Comment: Any von Neumann algebra $M$ has a unique positive linear map $\phi:M\to Z(M)$ such that $\phi(xy)=\phi(yx)$ for all $x,y\in M$, and $\phi(c)=c$ for all $c\in Z(M)$. This unique map happens to be faithful and normal.

Comment: You mentioned that "by adding orthogonal projections constructed above",I don't understand why the projections are orthogonal.For any $p$,there exist two equivalent projections $p_1$ and $p_2$ such that $p=p_1+p_2$,but $p_1,p_2$ may not be orthogonal.

Comment: If two projections add to a projection, then they are orthogonal. But that's irrelevant here: the halving is done by taking $p$, and getting a subprojection $\r leq p$ such that $r\equiv p-r$.